# NavigationLink from a Menu SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How do I navigate to a new page programmatically from the user choosing an action on the `Menu` view in SwiftUI? What I have here isn't navigating when I choose an option.

Example Code:

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @State var oneActive: Bool = false
    @State var twoActive: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
    
        Menu {
            Button {
                oneActive = true
            } label: {
                Text("Option One")
            }
        
            Button {
                twoActive = true
            } label: {
                Text("Option Two")
            }
    
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        }
    
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Option One View"), isActive: $oneActive) { EmptyView() }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Option Two View"), isActive: $twoActive) { EmptyView() }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("TItle")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    MenuView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar exists outside of the `NavigationView` hierarchy, which is why the `NavigationLink`s don't function within the `MenuView`. Instead, you can put the `NavigationLinks` inside the `NavigationView` and then send `Bindings` to the `MenuView`.

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @Binding var oneActive: Bool
    @Binding var twoActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Button {
                oneActive = true
            } label: {
                Text("Option One")
            }
        
            Button {
                twoActive = true
            } label: {
                Text("Option Two")
            }
    
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var oneActive: Bool = false
    @State private var twoActive: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Option One View"), isActive: $oneActive) { EmptyView() }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Option Two View"), isActive: $twoActive) { EmptyView() }
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("TItle")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    MenuView(oneActive: $oneActive, twoActive: $twoActive)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please enlighten. I do not see any difference between the two. Also having problem with opening a new page from menu, and it is inside a NavigationView

Comment: Check out the description, which details the difference. The NavigationLink has to be outside the Menu.

Comment: Right. That was the main difference :D. Got it to work. thank you